# Variable returning weird number

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm making a program for a challenge that was given to me: Take a string, find the ascii value of each of its letters, and add those numbers together and return the final value. I have got this far:

```
def AddAsciiList(string):
    ascii = [ord(c) for c in string]
    for item in ascii:
        print item
        total = ascii[i-1] + ascii[i]
    return total
string = raw_input("Enter String:")
AddAsciiList(string)
```

The "print item" statement was to help me see what was going wrong. I know that the total = statement isn't going to work yet, I'm getting to fixing it. Basically what I'm asking, is WHY does "print item" print the number 97?!

Comment: `ord('a') == 97`. And you must be having `a` somewhere in your string.

Comment: You don't seem to have defined `i` anywhere... Is this meant to be `item`?

Comment: Yes, I'm changing it.

Comment: @RohitJain, Yes, the string I enter for tests is abc. How do I figure out how many times I've gone through the for loop? Do I just have to set a value and increment it every time?

Comment: @EliasBenevedes. You can just do `len(string)`. But why do you want that in the first place?

Comment: @RohitJain To add the total of the numbers in the list, to finish the challenge.

Comment: @EliasBenevedes. Then just apply `sum` on your `list`.

Comment: Do you want to add up the ASCII codes of all the characters?

Comment: @RohitJain I didn't see you comment in time, but thanks. I got it figured out with this:

try:
        for item in ascii:
            total = total + ascii[r-1] 
            r += 1
            print r
    except IndexError:
        pass

Comment: So, you are trying to sum up the ASCII codes? Use the builtin `sum` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) returns the ASCII code of the number, and the `ascii` list contains the codes. See the example -

```
>>> testString = "test"
>>> testList = [ord(elem) for elem in testString]  # testList = map(ord, testString) is another way.
>>> testList
[116, 101, 115, 116]
```

And, when you iterate over the list, you get integer values which get printed out.

It prints `97` because you must be having an `'a'` in your input string, as

```
>>> chr(97)
'a'
```

See what the `help` function has to say -

```
>>> help(ord)
Help on built-in function ord in module __builtin__:

ord(...)
    ord(c) -> integer

    Return the integer ordinal of a one-character string.
```

If you want to add up all the ASCII codes for the characters in your string, do

```
>>> sum(map(ord, testString))
448
```

or

```
>>> sum(ord(elem) for elem in testString)
448
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second statement, you're creating a list of integers. Let's look at an example:

```
>>> s = 'abcde'
>>> a = [ord(c) for c in s]
>>> a
[97, 98, 99, 100, 101]
>>>
```

If you want to sum the items in the list, just use sum.

```
>>> sum(a)
495
```

If you want to do the whole thing in one swell foop:

```
>>> total = sum(ord(c) for c in s)
>>> total
495
```

Hope this helps.